# SUM of all fields in one column

Tags: sql, sum

Im trying to calculate the SUM of all the numbers in one column.

The column name is 'Units' the type in integer.

This should work?

```
cmd3 = New OleDbCommand("SELECT SUM(Units) FROM tblJobs WHERE BookedOut = NULL AND HoldDate = NULL ", con)

lblLiveUnits.Text = cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Thank you

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery will return the amount of rows affected, not a result. Use ExecuteScalar if you just want one item of data returning from a query: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is not correct, you do not want to make something `=NULL` you should use `IS NULL`:

```
SELECT SUM(Units)  As TotalUnits
FROM tblJobs 
WHERE BookedOut IS NULL 
  AND HoldDate IS NULL
```

Then in your code you will use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx):

```
Int32 lblLiveUnits = 0;

cmd3 = New OleDbCommand("SELECT SUM(Units)  As TotalUnits FROM tblJobs WHERE BookedOut IS NULL AND HoldDate IS NULL ", con);

lblLiveUnits = cmd3.ExecuteScalar()
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! with the new code i know get this error.  An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'WHERE OnHold = 1 AND BookedOut IS NULL'.

Comment: @user2286005 I incorrectly had two `WHERE`s listed.  Try that again

Comment: Sorry that was me being a sheep! with the correct code i now get this error? 
Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: Problem solved, they had the column type as string! Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @mjshort Glad you figured it out.